# Psycopg2 DictCursor returns nothing

Tags: postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

My query is:

```
query = '''
    SELECT * from table
    where id IN (SELECT ext_id from table2
            where title= %s and year = %s)
'''
```

Next i use

```
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=pg.extras.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(query, (title, year))
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

It  returns [], i.e. nothing

But if i set cursor = conn.cursor() the same query returns some rows! What's going wrong? Why do i can't use DictCursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code don't use ***pg***.extras.DictCursor.

instead I use ***psycopg2***.extras.DictCursor

I write the following:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
```

Then I'm able to access content using key.

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure (I have changed my code) but I tried it in another project and it seems to work as expected. Thanks!